# How do I fix my 'Path' field when editing pages via the Dashboard?

Tags: editor, dashboard

I am encountering the same problem described here: [Unable to set path](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/unable-to-set-path-in-a-static-page). In every module where I can edit a page, a `p` appears after the word 'Path'. I can click on it; clicking on it highlights some of the text.

How do I fix this issue? [image]

Comment: the path shows what html tag your in. It really is pointless. Mainly use for reference. it has nothing to deal with on your links just an editor feature.

Comment: @xLRDxREVENGEx: This was helpful. I'd be happy to push the answer to you if you make it an answer (assuming this is truly the answer since I wouldn't know if it wasn't :) )

Comment: Done. I added some examples and made it sexier for feature readers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path in the editor is just for reference, most of the time users do not even bother looking at it and those that do use if to see what html tag there are in.

**Example:**

```
<p>
This is just a sample paragraph
</p>
<span>
This is just a sample span
</span>
<blockquote>
This is just a simple blockquote
</blockquote>
```

If i was in the blockquote tags the path would be `PATH: blockquote` or in the span `PATH: span`. All in all the feature is use full to most and use less to some OR use full to beginners and use less to advance

Just a side note it does not have anything to do with the path of your site that is the line below the title field

Comment: So it's not the file path. Haha. That's why I thought it was broken.

Comment: @Avry: Correct!